# Problema al intentar registrarme con gema devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, devise, gemfile

Me sale el siguiente error cuando intento registrarme con un usuario, lleno los campos y le doy al sign up y de una:

> LoadError in Devise::SessionsController#create
>
> cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext.

Ya he intentado desinstalar e instalar nuevamente la gema bcrypt pero nada, me continúa el error. Me pueden ayudar se los agradezco.

Comment: Tal vez esta referencia te sirva: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42463755/3043906

Comment: Exactamente eso fue lo que hice ... pero me continua el error.

Comment: ¿Tu SO es Windows?, ¿qué versión de Ruby tienes?

Comment: Si , tengo windows 10 y la versión 5.0.7 de rails.

Comment: ¿Qué resultado obtienes al ejecutar el comando `gem list bcrypt`?

Answer (score 0):

Estos pasos para solucionar el problema en MS Win 10 y 8

Desinstalar todos bcrypt

```
gem uninstall bcrypt
```

Vaya en lib / ruby ​​/ gems / 2.3.0 / gems / bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32 / lib / y copie el archivo bcrypt_ext.so. y pegar en el escritorio por ahora.

Desinstalar todo bcrypt nuevamente

```
gem uninstall bcrypt
```

Agregue el archivo gem de su proyecto

```
gema 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
```

Ejecutar comandos

```
   bundle install
   bundle update
```

Pegue copiado bcrypt_ext.so en la carpeta lib / ruby ​​/ gems / 2.3.0 / gems / bcrypt-3.1.11-x86-mingw32 / lib / del escritorio.

Reiniciar el servidor

```
rails s
```

¡Funciona en Win 7 y 10!